# Perl: How to stop File::Find entering directory recursively?

Tags: perl

I was looking at Perl's `File::Find` module and tried it in the following way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Find;

find({wanted => \&listfiles,
        no_chdir => 1}, ".");


sub listfiles{
    print $File::Find::name,"\n";
}
```

Now When I run it I get the below output:

```
Noob@Noob:~/tmp$ perl test.pl 
.
./test.txt
./test.pl
./test1.txt
./hello
./hello/temp.txt
```

Now, I was thinking that by setting `no_chdir=>1` I will make my code to not enter any directory if it came across one. But the output clearly shows that my code is entering `hello` directory and listing its files.

So, how do I change my code to behave like `ls` and not enter any directory. Also I am getting `./` in front of my file/directory names can that be removed?

I am using Perl 5.14.

Comment: Make sure listfiles does not return true for directories. The man page indicates no_chdir requires your wanted fucntion to be aware of this.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Simply to list the files in a given directory? The `File::Find` module **traverses** directory trees. Though it's possible to make your wanted function skip over sub-directories and their contents, you'll end up doing way more work than you need to just to list the files in a single directory.

Comment: `no_chdir` doesn't prevent traversal, it just prevents the actual `chdir` system call.

Comment: If you do not want recursion, you might as well just `glob` or `opendir` to read the files in.

Comment: @JonahBishop: My ultimate goal was to write a program that performs `ls` function but than I ended up writing `print"$_ \n" for glob("*");`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$File::Find::prune` can be used to avoid recursing into a directory.

```
use File::Find qw( find );

my $root = '.';
find({
   wanted   => sub { listfiles($root); },
   no_chdir => 1,
}, $root);

sub listfiles {
   my ($root) = @_;
   print "$File::Find::name\n";
   $File::Find::prune = 1  # Don't recurse.
      if $File::Find::name ne $root;
}
```

You can set `prune` conditionally if you so desire.

```
use File::Basename qw( basename );
use File::Find     qw( find );

my %skip = map { $_ => 1 } qw( .git .svn ... );

find({
   wanted   => \&listfiles,
   no_chdir => 1,
}, '.');

sub listfiles {
   if ($skip{basename($File::Find::name)}) {
      $File::Find::prune = 1;
      return;
   }

   print "$File::Find::name\n";
}
```

`no_chdir` is not necessary — it has nothing to do with what you are trying to do — but I like what it does (prevents changes to the cwd), so I left it in.

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify what do you exactly mean by `prevents changes to the cwd`.

Comment: The current work directory (cwd) is the directory used to convert relative paths to absolute path. It's what [`chdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html) changes. By default, `find` will chdir into the directory in which the current file is located.

Comment: @ikegami; Unfortunately rather more than this is necessary because the first node to be reported is the node to be searched. Pruning this will result in a list of just that directory

Comment: @ikegami: Your code doesn't work for me it just print `.` and than it exits itself.

Comment: @Noob: that is because of the problem I mentioned. You would have to prune all directories except the one being searched in the `find` call

Answer (score 11):

Although I think that TLP's suggestion to use either `glob` or `opendir` is the best for your case, another option is to use [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.33/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm)--an interface for [Find::File](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.16.1/lib/File/Find.pm)--with `maxdepth(1)` to stop directory recursion:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $directory = '.';
my @files = File::Find::Rule->maxdepth( 1 )
                            ->file
                            ->name( '*.txt' )
                            ->in( $directory );
say for @files;
```

In this case, only `*.txt` file names will be passed to `@files`.

Sample output:

```
A.txt
B.txt
columns.txt
data.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to use the `preprocess` parameter to remove all directories from each directory being processed. That means it will never descend below the directories specified to be searched

The parameter list passed to the `preprocess` subroutine is the nodes in the current directory - the output of `readdir`. The returned value is the same list but sorted and filtered according to how you want them to be processed. This code just removes all directories

The best way to remove the initial `./` is to use `rel2abs` from [`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aSpec). Note here, enabling the `no_chdir` will break the code because by default `rel2abs` takes the current working directory as the base directory. Using `no_chdir` would mean explicitly passing a base directory parameter

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find 'find';
use File::Spec;

find({ wanted => \&listfiles, preprocess => \&nodirs }, '.');

sub nodirs {
  grep ! -d, @_;
}

sub listfiles {
  my $filename = File::Spec->abs2rel($File::Find::name);
  print $filename, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Nice, I like the preprocess parameter but I don't want my directory to be removed I  just want my output to look like `ls command` and I already know that I can write `print"$_ \n" for glob("*");` to achieve that but I was thinking of a way to achieve this using `File` module and its functions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You said you wanted to remove the `. /` from the front of the filename and this code does that. It displays the file's basename like `ls` does

Comment: @Borodin: I think what he meant is that ls displays all `files and directory` of a folder without entering any directory recursively unless specified by `-R flag`. what your code does is it displays all files fine but you have removed all the directories.

Answer (score 0):

Use *preprocess* and a nop for *"wanted"*

```
use File::Find qw( find );

my @f;

find(
{ 
    wanted => sub {},
    preprocess => sub {
        push(@f, grep !/^\.?\./,@_); # @_ is equivalent to readdir(DIR)
                                     # '.' and '..' come for free
        # find uses what you return here for processing. 
        # since nothing (an empty list) is returned, it has nothing to recurse on
     }
},
@dirs);
```

If you want full paths, then map the grep like so

```
push(@f, map { Spec->catfile($File::Find::dir,$_); } grep !/^\.?\./,@_);
```

Or, just

```
 push(@f, map { $File::Find::dir . '/' . $_); } grep !/^\.?\./,@_);
```

For the latter, you may get an intermixing of \ and / on Windows, depending on  how you specify elements of @dirs