# List all files recursively but exclude some directories (.git .svn)

Tags: perl

I would like to get all the files in a specified path but I want to exclude all the files inside some directories defined with:

```
 my $exclude = qw/.git .svn .cvs/;
```

The simplest method uses `File::Find`, but in the case of very big projects (under git or svn), the `find` subroutine will still iterates over all the files inside the excluded directories:

```
my $root = 'foo/';
my @files = do {
    my @f; 
    find(sub { 
        state $excluded = do {
            my $qr = join('|', map(quotemeta($_ =~ s/\/+$//r), @exclude));
            qr/$qr$/;
        }; 

        local $_ = $File::Find::name;
        next unless -f;
        next unless /$excluded/;
        push @f, $_;
    }, $root);
    @f;
}
```

The only solution I've found involving only core modules is to manually iterate with `readdir`. Is there a better method?

**EDIT**

A solution that works is this code below but It seems it is a bit complex for something that should be simple...

```
use 5.014;
my @exclude = qw/.git .svn .cvs/;  
my @files = parse_dir('.');
say join("\n", @files);

sub parse_dir {
    state $re = do {
        my $qr = join('|', map(quotemeta($_ =~ s/\/+$//r =~ s/^(\.\/)?/.\//r)  , @exclude));
        qr/$qr/;
    };

    my @files; 
    my $dir = shift;
    return unless -d $dir;
    opendir my $dh, $dir;

    while(my $file = readdir($dh))
    {
        $file = "$dir/$file";
        next if $file =~ /\/[.]{1,2}$/;
        next if $file =~ /$re/; 
        if (-f $file) {
            push @files, $file;       
        } elsif (-d $file) {            
            @files = (@files, parse_dir($file));
        }
    }               
    closedir $dh;
    @files;
}
```

Comment: See [Perl: How to stop File::Find entering directory recursively?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12334037/176646)

Comment: @ikegami I thought they were different enough (don't recurse into any directories vs. don't recurse into a specific set of directories) that I didn't vote to close. Not to say I wasn't tempted, considering that you were able to answer both with very similar code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$File::Find::prune` can be used to avoid recursing into a directory.

```
use File::Find qw( find );

sub wanted {
   state $excluded_re = do {
      my @excluded = qw( .git .svn .cvs );
      my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, @excluded;
      qr{(?:^|/)$pat\z/
   }

   if (/$excluded_re/) {
      $File::Find::prune = 1;
      return 0;
   }

   return -f;
}

my $root = 'foo';

my @files;
find({
   wanted   => sub { push @files, $_ if wanted() },
   no_chdir => 1,
}, $root);
```

---

This is the same approach one would take using the command line tool `find`.

```
find foo \( -name .git -o -name .svn -o -name .cvs \) -prune -o -print
```

Answer (score 4):

My search tool ack (http://search.cpan.org/dist/ack) does exactly this: It ignores .svn, .git and .cvs directories.

The problem you describe, where you must iterate over the entire tree to get results back when you use File::Find is exactly why I wrote File::Next (http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Next), to encapsulate the `readdir` calls that you have correctly concluded that you need, plus it only gives you files and not directories.

The way to do in File::Next what you're describing above would be roughly like this:

```
my %excluded = map { $_ => 1 } qw( .svn .git .cvs );
my $iter = File::Next::files( {
        descend_filter => sub { !$excluded{$_} },
    }, 'foo/'
);
while ( my $file = $iter->() ) {
    # Do something with $file
}
```

I realize you're looking to use only core modules, but File::Next relies on no non-core modules.  Also, if you wanted you could just steal the iterator code from File::Next and put it directly into your project.  It's fairly simple, and it's adapted from code out of the excellent book *Higher Order Perl* (http://hop.perl.plover.com/).

Comment: I suspect what you're asking is to see quantitative measurements comparing the speed of File::Next vs. File::Find.  I don't have any, but I believe that their speed is comparable.

Answer (score 1):

Filter out the names you want to exclude in preprocess

```
use File::Find qw( find );

my $root = '.';

find({
   wanted   => sub {} # whatever you do with each found entry
   preprocess => sub { grep(!/\.(git|svn|cvs|\.$)/,@_) }
}, $root);
```

What gets returned from preprocess callback is the list of file/directory name that will get processed subsequently. Since .git, .svn, and .cvs aren't there, those won't be seen and touched.

A bit more detailed "lay man" explanation is at [Perl: How to stop File::Find entering directory recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334037/perl-how-to-stop-filefind-entering-directory-recursively/36964911#36964911) based on what is documented in [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html)

If you want just the directory listing, return an empty list.